# Why is IE 9 so slow at this DOM benchmark?

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-9

Link to test: http://nontroppo.org/timer/Hixie_DOM.html

[image]

Comment: Because IE sucks.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Did'nt see that one coming ;)

Comment: Without including the code you're testing in the question, it will be useless to future readers once you remove your demo page. If you're not asking if you're doing something that could be optimized, then there really isn't much of a question.

Comment: @Ryan: What kind of answers do you exactly expect here? On what level of detail?

Comment: @inflagranti I thought someone might know something about the differences between the way the different browsers are handling the same code. Looks like hradac had an idea below.

Comment: @user113716 Isn't the code available at the link I provided? It must be linked to the page somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest issue I saw was the index `testIndex` function which in your screenshot takes just over 8 seconds in IE9. Which is copied below for reference.

```
function testIndex(div) {
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
        divs[i] = div.childNodes[count*2 - i*2 - 1];
    }
}
```

Note that `divs` is an array with 10000 indexes.

There are quiet a few things going on in this function and I think the slow down happens because browsers other than IE have optimized these types of DOM manipulations and calculation caching. I think part of the problem is that this function, unlike all the others, adds a copy of what it finds to the `divs` array. So it crawls the DOM, copies the object it finds to an array. IE has never been terribly fast when crawling the DOM. Try the following and see what the difference is.

```
function testIndex(div) {
    var doublecount = (count*2) -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
        div.childNodes[doublecount - i*2];
    }
}
```

That may speed things up.